# vb.net code to divide the strings as required

Tags: string, vb.net, desktop

I am totally new to string programing and trying to develop a program in VB.Net wherein I am unable to differentiate Students and Lecturers from a single Field.

Sample Data in Field
TextBox1.Text= "1.(STU) KOLATI RAJA GOPAL , 2.(STU)MIRZA SHAFIULLAH BAIG , 3.(LEC)FAROOQ HUSSAI"

Desired Output

TextBox2.Text= "1.(STU) KOLATI RAJA GOPAL , 2.(STU)MIRZA SHAFIULLAH BAIG" //for students
TextBox3.Text="3.(LEC)FAROOQ HUSSAI"    //for Lecturers

```
Public FullPName As String
FullPName = UCase(TextBox1.Text)

 It1 = FullPName.IndexOf(SExe1)
 If It1 <> -1 Then
     For It1 = 0 To Len(FullPName - 1)
         Get1 = FullPName(It1)
     Next
 End If
```

Comment: As with all programming problems, start by working out the logic. What steps would you perform if you had to do it manually? Anyone can do that. Only once you have worked out the logic and formalised it into an algorithm should you consider writing code and the code should implement the logic specifically. If you can't explain what the code has to do, of course you can't write code to do it. So, what is the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim aSTringArray() As String

    ' Split the string by commas, ignoring empties
    aSTringArray = TextBox1.Text.Split(CType(",", Char()), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    For Each S In aSTringArray

        If S.Contains("STU") Then

            AppentTextbox(TextBox2, S)

        ElseIf S.Contains("LEC") Then

            AppentTextbox(TextBox3, S)

        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub AppentTextbox(TB As TextBox, S As String)

    If TB.Text = "" Then
        TB.Text &= S
    Else
        TB.Text &= ", " & S
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. NickAbbot. It worked.

Comment: Why convert a `String` literal to a `Char` when you can use a `Char` literal?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Because my VS2022 made that suggestion and I took it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney .NET Framework doesn't have a `String.Split(char, StringSplitOptions)` overload (.NET Core 2.0+ does), but it does have `String.Split(char(), StringSplitOptions)`, so I guess that is where Visual Studio got its suggestion from. Shame it doesn't suggest the more concise and readable `{","c}`, but I guess there's a reason I don't know about.

Comment: @NickAbbot If there is an entry like "4.(LEC)STUART ABADI" it will go into the list of students.

Answer (score -2):

This snippet selects into two variables the two different casts. Form it to your exact request.

```
Sub STU_LEC()

t1 = "1.(STU) KOLATI RAJA GOPAL , 2.(STU)MIRZA SHAFIULLAH BAIG , 3.(LEC)FAROOQ HUSSAI"
t2 = split(t1, ",")
For i = 0 To UBound(t2)
If InStr(1, t2(i), "(STU)") <> 0 Then
coll2 = coll2 & t2(i)
ElseIf InStr(1, t2(i), "(LEC)") <> 0 Then
coll3 = coll3 & t2(i)
End If
Next i
TextBox2.Text = coll2
TextBox3.Text = coll3
End Sub
```